# Different result while training in CPU and GPU for Google BERT

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I was running few examples exploring the pytorch version of Google's new pre-trained model called the [Google BERT](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT). I ran the example in both CPU as well as GPU machines. I run the following code for sentence pair classification using the [MRPC data](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52398) as given in the [readme](https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT#fine-tuning-with-bert-running-the-examples)

`python run_classifier.py \
  --task_name MRPC \
  --do_train \
  --do_eval \
  --do_lower_case \
  --data_dir $GLUE_DIR/MRPC/ \
  --bert_model bert-base-uncased \
  --max_seq_length 128 \
  --train_batch_size 32 \
  --learning_rate 2e-5 \
  --num_train_epochs 3.0 \
  --output_dir /tmp/mrpc_output/`

I get the following results.
In the CPU machine:

```
12/06/2018 02:01:20 - INFO - __main__ -   label: 0 (id = 0)
12/06/2018 02:01:21 - INFO - __main__ -   ***** Running evaluation *****
12/06/2018 02:01:21 - INFO - __main__ -     Num examples = 408
12/06/2018 02:01:21 - INFO - __main__ -     Batch size = 8
12/06/2018 02:04:24 - INFO - __main__ -   ***** Eval results *****
12/06/2018 02:04:24 - INFO - __main__ -     eval_accuracy = 0.8259803921568627
12/06/2018 02:04:24 - INFO - __main__ -     eval_loss = 0.40949390638692706
12/06/2018 02:04:24 - INFO - __main__ -     global_step = 345
12/06/2018 02:04:24 - INFO - __main__ -     loss = 0.22680548837651376
```

In the GPU machine:

```
12/06/2018 04:43:55 - INFO - __main__ -   label: 0 (id = 0)
12/06/2018 04:43:55 - INFO - __main__ -   ***** Running evaluation *****
12/06/2018 04:43:55 - INFO - __main__ -     Num examples = 408
12/06/2018 04:43:55 - INFO - __main__ -     Batch size = 8
12/06/2018 04:44:49 - INFO - __main__ -   ***** Eval results *****
12/06/2018 04:44:49 - INFO - __main__ -     eval_accuracy = 0.678921568627451
12/06/2018 04:44:49 - INFO - __main__ -     eval_loss = 0.5874785494570639
12/06/2018 04:44:49 - INFO - __main__ -     global_step = 345
12/06/2018 04:44:49 - INFO - __main__ -     loss = 0.5948529090570367
```

Why are the results coming different? And also there is a very significant difference.

Comment: Did you use same random seed before the training?

Comment: @Tim random seed was not used i guess (https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/blob/master/examples/run_classifier.py) . But is that relevant here. There is no partitioning of the data here. We give separate train, test and dev sets.

Comment: I didn't check the code, but setting a random seed is a cheap check that can be easily done when in doubt. Most of the algorithms have some kind of randomization (e.g. initializing weights).

Comment: @Tim makes sense. I was thinking may be the batch size or sequence length might cause dramatic effect when run on CPU or GPU.

Comment: @prashanth one other thing which might be an issue is if the two devices use difference random number generation code. GPUs often have PRNGs which are specialized for the hardware on those devices, setting the same seed alone may not guarantee same results. There are also differences in how floating point rounding is handled on the two types of devices. These may all contribute to differences between the two code execution results.